# How can I configure default route metric with dhcp and netplan?

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan

My problem is quite similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/984445). My vagrant machine sets default route metric incorrectly.

The following is netplan configuration.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 02:70:4e:c8:68:e9
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.33.10/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.33.1
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.33.0/24
          via: 192.168.33.1
          metric: 0
```

And route table.

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.33.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s8
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp0s3
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
192.168.33.0    192.168.33.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s8
```

`enp0s3` is NAT interface and internet connection should use this. `sudo route del default enp0s8` resolves this problem, but adding routes to yaml couldn't solve the problem and has the limit of fixed gateway.

What configuration should I use to reorder metrics automatically?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For systems with multiple interfaces, only the interface that should get the default gateway should have "gateway4:" set; keeping in mind that DHCP is quite likely to set the default gateway as well:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 02:70:4e:c8:68:e9
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.33.10/24]
```

Note that the additional route you had set is typically unneeded: 192.168.33.0/24 is already reachable, as it is directly connected to the `enp0s8` interface in this case (when `addresses:` lists the subnet already). Having a `metric:` set to 0 can further confuse the kernel.

If you need the interface with static IP (in this case `enp0s8` to have the default gateway instead of the interface that does DHCP, then you can set a route with a metric value **lower** than 100; so that it is picked **before** the default gateway set via DHCP by *systemd-networkd*. For example:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 02:70:4e:c8:68:e9
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.33.10/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.33.1
          metric: 50
```

Comment: Additionally it is possible to change metrics weight with `dhcp4-overrides: {route-metric: 100}`, [ref](https://netplan.io/examples)

Comment: 5 years later and still useful...I was searching for a solution to my problem for 2 hours until I found this thank you so much