# Two network cards configured with the same network segment IP

Tags: networking, netplan, router

I have a ubuntu server with two network cards.
The IP of eth0 is 192.168.2.178/24, and the IP of eth1 is 192.168.2.179/24.
This is my config with netplan:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.2.178/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.2.1
      optional: true
    eth1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.2.179/24
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

When I finished configuring the network, two rules appeared in the routing table.

| Destination | Gateway | Genmask | Flags | Metric | Ref | Use | Iface |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.2.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 255.255.255.0 | U | 0 | 0 | 0 | eth0 |
| 192.168.2.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 255.255.255.0 | U | 0 | 0 | 0 | eth1 |

There will be a conflict when accessing other IPs in the 192.168.2.0/24 network segment.
I hope to access 192.168.2.100 through the eth1 network card, and access other IPs through the eth0 network card. How to achieve this effect by configuring netplan and making it permanent.

I have tried manually setting up a route.

```shell
$ route del -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
$ route add -host 192.168.2.100 dev eth1
```

But when the ubuntu server restarts or unplugs the network cable, the routing table will be restored.

Comment: You should set route priorities.

Comment: Please help me, how to set route priorities?

Comment: I have no practical information, but https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008571/ may help.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your use case,
but maybe you can set the cards with different ip segmant like:
192.168.2.0
192.168.1.0

or maybe you can add a route with a higher netmask like
192.168.2.178 255.255.255.255