# Static IP address in a VirtualBox machine running Ubuntu 18.04 server LTS

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 18.04, dns

I am struggling to set up a static IP address in Ubuntu server 18.04 server LTS. The OS is running in a VirtualBox machine.

What I have done so far:

1. Created a VM.
2. Added a "NAT and a "Host-only" adapter to the network settings in VirtualBox.
3. Installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.
4. Configured netplan with static IP settings matching IP of "Host-only adapter.
5. Ran `netplan apply`
6. Ran `netplan --debug generate` to check syntax accuracy. (Passed)
7. Rebooted server

My current netplan configuration as described by the netplan documentation:

[image: netplan configuration - host]

Ping results in an error message: Temporary failure in name resolution.

[image: ping result - host]

Gateway and nameserver addresses are set to the IP of the NAT  adapter in VirtualBox's "Host Network Manager" as per screenshot:

[image: Host Network Manager - VB]

The "Host-only" adapter is added to the VM under adapter 2:

[image: Network adapter settings -VB]

This is configured in netplan as enp0s8.

Changing the configuration back to DHCP using eth0s3 allows name resolution, but the moment I switch back to eth0s8 with a static configuration I am unable to resolve to any domains.

Update:
See the result of "route -n"

[image: result of route n]

Please assist.

Comment: I had the exact problem.  The solution was to remove the gateway4 entry from the enp0s8 ethernet config as described here ... https://askubuntu.com/a/1051542/22667

Comment: Please check out either the detailed description on how to set everything up https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457240/301403 or the original solution / working netplan https://askubuntu.com/a/1051542/851428. I hope it solves the issue you are having.